# How to repopulate form table rows that were generated dynamically with java script

Tags: codeigniter

I have an input form that’s used to specify information about a “volunteer”. The volunteer can be a single person or a group of people. At the bottom of the form there is a checkbox that’s selected when the information is about a group of people. When it’s selected, I use jquery to show a DIV that has a table (initially just 1 row) where information about the other members of the group can be entered.

The user can click an image to trigger a jquery script function that will dynamically add a row to the table.

My problem is that I can’t figure out how to repopulate the values in the row(s) if the form has to be redisplayed because of a validation error. Since I’m generating the HTML with script, I can’t put in PHP code because it gets interpreted at the time the page is loaded.

Maybe there is a better way to do this whole thing (and I’m open to suggestions) but here’s what I have now.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Here’s the jQuery script to add new row:

```
function addMember() {  
  var $counter = parseInt($("#rowCounter").val());  
  if ($counter > 1) {  
    var $firstName = "#firstName"+$counter;  
    var $lastName = "#lastName"+$counter;  
    var $email = "#email"+$counter;  
    if ($($firstName).val() == "" && $($lastName).val() == "" && $($email).val() == "") {  
      alert("You must fill out member row before adding another!");  
      return false;  
    }  
  }  
  $memberRowNum = $counter;  
  $counter+=1;  
  var $appendVal = '<tr><td>'+$memberRowNum+'<input type="hidden" name="volID'+$counter+'" id="volID'+$counter+'"></td>';  
  $appendVal += '<td><input type="text" name="firstName~~" id="firstName~~" size="15" ></td>';  
  $appendVal += '<td><input type="text" name="lastName~~" id="lastName~~" size="20" ></td>';  
  $appendVal += '<td><input type="text" name="email~~" id="email~~" size="25" ></td>';  
  $appendVal += '<td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="student_~~" id="student_~~"  /></td>';  
  $appendVal += '<td><select name="grade_~~" id="grade_~~"><option value=""></option><option value="13">College</option></option><option value="12">12th</option><option value="11">11th</option><option value="10">10th</option><option value="9">9th</option><option value="8">8th</option><option value="7">7th</option><option value="6">6th</option><option value="5">5th</option><option value="4">4th</option><option value="3">3rd</option></select></td>';  
  $appendVal += '</tr>';  
  $appendVal = $appendVal.replace(/~~/g,$counter);  
  $appendVal = $appendVal.replace(/@@/g,"?");  
  $(".groupMembers > tbody:last").append($appendVal);  
  $("#rowCounter").val($counter);  
}
```

Here’s the HTML/PHP snippet after which, the row(s) are appended:

```
<li><label>Are you registering as Group?</label><?php echo form_checkbox($asGroup);?>
<span id="handleGroupInfo">
<br>Group Name:<?php echo form_input($groupName);?>
<br><br>List names and emails of all group members below. Click plus sign to add more members to group<br>
<table class="groupMembers">
<tbody>
<th>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img id="add_row" alt="Add Group Member" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/green-plus-sign-tiny.png" />&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>email</th>
<th>Student?</th>
<th>Grade</th>
</tbody>
</table>
</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

With your current implementation, try passing the total number of members through hidden input

```
<input type="hidden" name="total_member" value="<?= $this->input->post('total_member'); ?>" />
```

That way, you know the total number of submitted members and when on validation error,

```
<?php if(validation_errors()): ?>
  <?php for($i = 0; $i < $this->input->post('total_member'); $i++): ?>
    // For example...
    <td><input type="text" name="firstName<?= $i; ?>" id="firstName<?= $i; ?>" value="<?= $this->input->post('firstName' . $i); ?>" size="15" ></td>
    // And so no...
  <?php endfor; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

*Note: I didn't check syntax. Just as an example...

Comment: That's kind of what I ended up doing. I was hoping there would be a "cleaner" way to do it but this works. Thanks